# Google Sheets arrayformula vlookup transpose matching values and return all unique values in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I need an arrayformula to lookup all matching cells in another sheet and transpose and return all corresponding unique values.

Here is my sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uqeM6M9MAPehgyqyRLmH9mgg3Jh_RUSxADMisarht5Y/edit?usp=sharing

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(A2:A), Sheet2!A2:B, 2, 0)))
```

Comment: could you please add in your sheet an example of the expected outcome?

Comment: Ok no problem. Thats added now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 {SORT(UNIQUE(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A2:A"&COUNTA(Sheet2!A2:A)+1))), 
 SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(ISNUMBER(QUERY(QUERY(UNIQUE(Sheet2!A2:B), 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0), "offset 1", 0)), 
 "♦"&QUERY(UNIQUE(Sheet2!A2:B), 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2 limit 0", 0), ))
 ,,999^99))), "♦")}, {1,2,3,4,5,6}, 0))
```

[image: 0]